# Max velocity before toppling risk

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

I want to find out the maximum velocity a machine can travel before there is a risk of toppling.

Say, worst case, is that the castors hit a dead stop and the machine is brought to rest 'instantaneously' by a force acting on the wheels.

So the question is at what speed will it have enough energy to topple?

My thoughts are if the machine is to topple then the centre of gravity must move outside of the base footprint so that the moments then cause it to topple rather than righting itself, as in a static problem.

As the machine is toppling then it will rotate, as it rotates then the centre  of gravity will have to move upwards against gravity.

If it has enough energy to rotate against gravity to the point where the centre of gravity moves outside of the base then it will topple.

This is why are an object with a large footprint and low Centre of gravity would be more stable when in motion as the centre of gravity would have a large distance against gravity to move due to the geometry about which it rotates.

I am pretty sure this is correct however would like to see you fine people concur?

See image to illustrate. [image]

Comment: Yes, this looks completely correct to me! The easiest way is indeed by checking if the kinetic energy is sufficient to raise the COM by the height required for toppling.